# デジタル時計をリアルタイムで表示させたい

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、アナログ時計の周囲にデジタル時計を表示させたものですが、
更新ボタンを押さないとリアルタイムで表示できません。
これを更新ボタンを押さなくても、デジタル時計をリアルタイムで表示させ続けること
(=動いている状態)は可能でしょうか。可能でしたら、ご教示ください。

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }

    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}


var dCol = '00ff00', //date colour.
    sCol = 'ff0000', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '000000', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '000000', //hours colour.
    fCol = '0000ff', //face color
    ClockHeight = 40,
    ClockWidth = 40,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100;
 var   ti = new Date;
 var   da = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
 var   m = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

 var year = ti.getYear() + 1900;
 var month = m[ti.getMonth()];
 var date = ti.getDate();
 var day = da[ti.getDay()];

     var Hour = ti.getHours();
     var Min = ti.getMinutes();
     var Sec = ti.getSeconds();

        if(Hour <= 9) { 
                       Hour = "\u0020\u0020" + Hour; 
}        
　　　　if(Min <= 9) { 
                       Min = "0" + Min; 
}
        if(Sec <= 9) { 
                       Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
}

var TodaysDate = "★★★★★★★" + Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec +"★★★★★★★"+Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;

var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '...';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '....';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '.....';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.6;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.06,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];

var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}

var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';


// Date wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Hours wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Minute wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Seconds wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Mouse move event handler
function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }


}
document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;

}

function Delay() 
{

    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);

    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);

}

Delay();


}());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

追記
setTimeout(Delay, 20);後にnowtime();を加え、Delay()の後にfunction nowtime(){}として、
その中に即時関数全体を入れると秒針は動くのですが、時計の右下4分の1しか描写されません。

Comment: Delay関数がsetTimeoutによって繰り返し実行されることで時計を動かす実装になっていますが、そこにデジタル時計の内容を更新するコードが含まれていないようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。デジタル時計‌​の内容を更新するコードとは、"var ti=～var TodaysDate=～;"までですが、それをDelay関数内に入れるのは試してみたのですが、秒針は止まったままです。何か記述が不足しているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClockAndAssign()`内にデジタル時計の文字を更新する処理が必要です。

1. `TodaysDate`と`D`を更新する
   `var   ti = new Date;`から`var D = TodaysDate.split('');`までを加える
2. 各DIV.Date内のSPANを`innerHTML`で更新する
   `// Date wrapper`から`$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;`までを加える

以上で動くはずです。

---

追記：以下質問とは直接関係ありません。また、提示されているプログラム全体を理解されているorする予定がある場合のお話です。そうでない、もしくはCSSについての知識がなければ無視してください。

これはアドバイスですが、for文内で毎回`$$('クラス名')`を何度も呼び出すのは処理効率が悪いので、事前に変数に入れておくことをお勧めします。
また、変化しないstyle属性はstyleタグか外部ファイルのCSSに置き換えるとビジュアルとプログラムが分離されて可読性が良くなります。以下は分離した例です。

```html
<style>
  #clock {
    /* 時計全般で使うフォントの設定 */
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em; /* size変数の値 */
  }
  #clock DIV {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  #clock .Date {
    text-align: center;
    color: #00ff00; /* dCol変数の値 */
  }
  /*.. 同じ要領で .Face, .Hours, .Minutes, .Seconds にも適用する */
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    //~~ 中略 ~~
    var D = TodaysDate.split('');
    var H = '...';
    H = H.split('');
    var M = '....';
    M = M.split('');
    var S = '.....';
    S = S.split('');
    var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
        speed = 0.6;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
    var n = Face.length;
    var a = size * 10;
    var ymouse = 0,
        xmouse = 0,
        scrll = 0;
    var Split = 360 / n;
    var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
    //~~ 中略 ~~
    // Date wrapper
    html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) {
        html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';">' + D[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
    //~~ 中略 ~~
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。コピペしてみましたが、画面に何も表示されなくなりましたが…

Comment: 提示したコードはプログラムを理解されている前提で、より分かりやすく見渡しの良いプログラムにするための参考用として書きました。質問内容とは直接関係ないので無視してください。
冒頭の手順に少し追記しましたので、まずはそちらだけお試しください。

Comment: お手数かけました。ClockAndAssign()内のことは試していたのですが、"var D = TodaysDate.split('');"まで入れないと"秒"は動かないのですね。希望通りになりました。setTimeoutは、いじらなくてよかったのですね。CSSの説明も、ありがとうございました。